# Pass custom header to two different domains ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webrequest

I'm trying to pass a custom header  from one app to another without success, these apps arre hosted on different domains.

Is it posible to do so?

I have this so far.

```
//App1:
Response.AddHeader("CustomH","Value")
Response.Redirect("differentedomain.com")

//App2:
var customh = Request.Headers["CustomH"]
```

But on the second domain the request headers are null.

Another thing I tried to do was make a WebRequest to the second app and pass the custom header throug, and It passed Ok, So, then I tried to make a Response.Redirect on the second app but before I set up a session variable

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["token"] = token;
Response.Redirect(Path.GetFileName(Path), false);
```

but when I get the final page my session has changed and my session variables has lost.

Is there any way to keep the same session on Response.Redirect????

Regards.

**UPDATE**

Ok this what i have so far

Domain A

```
Dim requestUrl As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(path + "Token.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)
                requestUrl.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
                requestUrl.Headers.Add("tokenHeader", token)
                Dim responseUrl As HttpWebResponse = CType(requestUrl.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                For Each cookie As System.Net.Cookie In responseUrl.Cookies
                    requestUrl.CookieContainer.Add(New Net.Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Domain))
                Next
                Response.Redirect(url)
```

As you can see on my first App I Set up my token on the headers and then make a call with the HttpWebRequest

Doamin B

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
```

After some validations with the token, I Set the Auth Cookie, and then after that I go back to the domain A to Redirect to my final url but when I do that the cookie is emtpy on domain B

Comment: You need to set a 3rd-party cookie in domain1 that is for domain2 so that when the browser calls domain2 it will deliver that cookie. All that assumes the browser doesn't have 3rd-party cookies blocked or privacy enabled or something else to interfere, so reliability would be questionable. Maybe if you told us more about what you're really trying to accomplish (the bigger picture) we could be more helpful.

Comment: The bigger pic is simple, I have an app lets call it App A and another one App B, where App A has an Iframe to embed some forms from App B, So, basiclly I have to call App B throgu a link to my form and pass a token to it where the token is responsible of give all parameters to log in to App B, what I need rite now is a easy way and secure to pass that token, so far I'm passing it to my App B through a form with POST Method inside a hidden input and on App B I get it from Request.Form["Token"], but I see this way in some way not secure I guess

Comment: Any idea about this my friend MrGadget ???

Comment: Look at [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) in server-side code on DomainA to initiate a session on DomainB to get session cookies from DomainB that you can set in your DomainA page as 3rd-party [HttpCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie(v=vs.110).aspx)s.  Pull bits from those links to build your solution.

Comment: By setting 3rd party cookies in your main page output, the browser will pass them along when it calls the URL of the iframe.

Comment: Well I've been trying to do so, but not success, @MrGadget I've updated the question with some example I've been trying so far. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Get rid of that redirect and review the link I gave above for HttpCookies to set the cookies you got in your code to the page output for the browser to capture and deliver through the iFrame pointed to domain B.